# CRED form in Types Toolset gives JS error when trying to add a notification

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, types, view

I'm using the Types Toolset plugin (CRED form actually), and every time I try to click the button that says "Add another Notification", the data doesn't open in the backend to enter the information.

Instead I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.switchEditors.switchto is not a function
```

This is the line of code that error is attached to:

```
window.switchEditors.switchto(document.getElementById(newId + '-tmce'));
```

Any idea what I should do? The plugin work perfectly except the JS error doesn't open the notification details in the back-end.